# Php на продакшн

Tags: php, развертывание

Есть проект на PHP, посоветуйте способы как удобно и красиво заливать изменения на продакшн. Желательно хранить несколько последних версий для быстрого возврата к прежней версии. Буду благодарен за любые советы.

Comment: Возврат к прежней версии - задача простая, пока нет миграций в базе. Потом обычно люди останавливаются на накатывании реверсивного релиза, релиза, который отменяет изменения предыдущего(или нескольких) По поводу самого деплоя, собираете релиз приложения, rsync в папку на сервере, переключаете ссылку с текущей версии на свежую. Её же и обратно можно переключить, если бы не миграции базы)

Comment: Мне интересно, при запуске скрипта выкачать ветку мастер из гита в новую папку и повесить на неё ссылку. Для этого и ищу готовые решения.  С базой пока в полу ручном режиме приходится, поэтому ее пока не рассматриваем. Для этого и ищу готовые красивые решения именно для файлов сервера.

Comment: Деплой через гит не очень корректен, если в гите исходный код. Можно, конечно, сделать отдельную репу для релизных сборок, но зачем вам оверхед в виде папки `.git`?... Основная идея в том, что доставлять на сервер нужно уже собранное приложение, никаких composer install и т.п. Собираете локально(на сборочном сервере), проверяете эту сборку на тестовых/стейджинговых серверах, если есть, потом её же на продакшн. Я использую rsync через ansible для доставки.

Comment: Можете посмотреть в сторону rocketeer http://rocketeer.autopergamene.eu Не очень прост в настройках, но взамен получаете почти сине-зеленый деплой, в крации он создает новую папку спуливаете код и переключает simlink. Так же можете посмотреть в сторону докерезации приложения к примеру kubernetes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно написать деплой проекта на том-же [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). Предусмотреть всё от создания каталогов с необходимыми правами до создания необходимых баз и вливания инициализирующих данных. На ансибле это всё делается достаточно легко.

Следующий шаг - поднятие и настройка CI и написание правил, которые по коммиту будут автоматически выкатывать код на stage например.

Comment: Вот именно вторая часть меня интересует намного больше, может есть какие то готовые решения, не смог найти нечего достаточно простого и лаконичного.

Comment: Если проект закрытый, то вам нужен тот же gitlab развернуть, у него есть инструменты нужные. Но начать всётаки нужно с ансибла. Его потом и в CI прикрутить можно будет уже.

Comment: Какое отношение к деплою имеют CI и staging? По коммиту на прод лучше ничего не выкатывать)

Comment: Мне интересно, при запуске скрипта выкачать ветку мастер из гита в новую папку и повесить на неё ссылку. Для этого и ищу готовые решения.  С базой пока в полу ручном режиме приходится, поэтому ее пока не рассматриваем. Для этого и ищу готовые красивые решения.

Comment: `> Какое отношение к деплою имеют CI и staging? ` stage - это всего лишь отдельный полигон, равно как и dev. prod конечно же все боятся из ci обновлять, но зря. При хорошо настроенных процессах, когда на stage пропускают несущественное количество багов, ничего не мешает и prod обновлять об CI.

Comment: `Мне интересно, при запуске скрипта выкачать ветку мастер из гита в новую папку и повесить на неё ссылку.` Сделайте один раз руками, потом запишите эти команды в скрипт, параметризируйте и используйте.

Comment: @vp_arth по коммиту в master, запушить который могут только избранные, выкатывать вполне можно (хотя, возможно, не нужно)